# how to determine page(cache) boundaries when writing to a file

Tags: linux, file, kernel

In linux when writing to a file, kernel maintains multiple in memory pages (4KB in size). Data is first written to the pages and background process bdflush sends these data to disk drive.

Is there a way to determine page boundaries  when writing sequentially to a file ?

Can I assume it is always 1-4096:page 1 and 4097-8192:page 2 ?

or can it vary ?

say if I start writing from 10 (i.e. first 10 bytes already written to the file previously and I set file position to 10 before start writing) will the page boundary  still be

1-4096 : page 1

OR

10-5096 : page 1 ?

Reason for asking,

I can use sync_file_range
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync_file_range.2.html
to flush data from kernel pages to disk drive in a orderly manner.
If I can determine page boundaries I can call sync_file_range only when a page boundary is reached, so that unnecessary sync_file_range calls are avoided.

Edit : 
Only positive thing to suggest such boundary alignment I could find was in mmap page asking offset to be multiple of page size
,

> offset must be a multiple of the page size as
>          returned by sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)

Comment: Hi @aKumara, have you seen [this](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)?

Comment: Hi @RobertoGonçalves,
Could you pls let me know which section in setrlimit page you are referring to ?

Comment: Sure! I was looking to your problem and it seems a interesting one, rlimit has a lot of features for you to customize it, like RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, RLIMIT_FSIZE, RLIMIT_DATA, my suggestion is to make some changes on those values and analyze  it.